# How can I synchronize my joomla users to OCS2 PKP conference site?

Tags: authentication, joomla, single-sign-on, ocs

I have a website in joomla 3.9 I need to connect the users to a OCS2 pkp conference management system to not register them again in the conference management site.
the data bases are hosting in one server.

Comment: If you are a Joomla user or developer, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla-related questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You will user event to get the data and curl to send/pass the data to OCS system. On the OCS portal, you can create a simple PHP to listen POST and then you process the data into your OCS database.

The `data` in onUserAfterSave has all the values of the user. the `$isNew` check if this is a new user or existing user making an update.

```
public function onUserAfterSave($data, $isNew, $result, $error) {}
```